# Relationships between entities in different contexts

Tags: entity-framework

In our project we have modules (extensions) for base project. Every module have its own entities, context and migrations. Now I have **ModuleA** and **ModuleB**.

In **ModuleA** I declare `EntityA`:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

In **ModuleB** I declare `EntityB` with navigation property of type `EntityA`:

```
public class EntityB
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string EntityAId { get; set; }

    public EntityA EntityA { get; set; }
}
```

I want to cascade delete entities B, related to entity A, when A deletes:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityB>().HasRequired(x => x.EntityA).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.EntityAId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

The problem is what when I try to create new migration for **ModuleB**, EF creates tables and columns for `EntityA` too (which already exists in **ModuleA**). Is there any way to estabilish relationship between `EntityA` and `EntityB`, when they use different contexts?

Comment: Are the contexts different databases? Usually related objects would share a context.

Comment: @AustinWinstanley No, they use same database and both contexts are inherited from same class.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to include them in 2 different contexts? Are ModuleA and ModuleB different projects? I'm trying to figure out why 2 contexts are necessary for related objects.

Comment: @AustinWinstanley It's two diffrent solutions which may be maintained by two different developer groups or event third-party developers.

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to link completely separate projects like that. You could look into providing a data SDK or JSON API for the different projects. But managing related parts of a database, as in, cascade operations, on entities that live in completely different solutions, is going to cause a lot of problems.